# How do you find a local max/min if the funciton is not differentiable there?

Tags: calculus

I was reviewing some multivariable calculus and thought of a question: we can find local extrema of a function by setting the derivative to zero, but what if at the point where the local max/min actually is, the function isn't differentiable?

For example, abs(x) or something like that.

I probably just forgot how to do this, or maybe we can't calculate the local extrema this way and have to approximate it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a problem even when you consider smooth functions restricted to a closed set. What you do in these situations is find the local extrema the normal way (setting the derivative to zero and solving) and then also evaluating your function at the points where it fails to be differentiable. Compare the values from all these points, and you should be able to find your min/max.

Comment: Ok , thanks. I actually just found an example in my book, which is -sqrt(x^2 + y^2) which has a local and global max at (0,0) even though the partial derivatives are undefined there. Makes sense.